# Failed to build dotenv v0.15.0 - rust cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I'm facing a problem trying to build a project that uses this this crate.

I'm running inside the docker rust:1.44.0.
I have installed the nightly:

```sh
rustup toolchain install nightly
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2020-06-12, rust version 1.46.0-nightly (a37c32e2d 2020-06-11)
info: downloading component 'cargo'
  5.0 MiB /   5.0 MiB (100 %)   1.5 MiB/s in  2s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
 15.9 MiB /  15.9 MiB (100 %)  15.0 MiB/s in  1s ETA:  0s
info: downloading component 'rustc'
 47.3 MiB /  47.3 MiB (100 %)  10.9 MiB/s in  5s ETA:  0s
info: installing component 'cargo'
info: installing component 'rust-std'
 15.9 MiB /  15.9 MiB (100 %)   9.1 MiB/s in  1s ETA:  0s
info: installing component 'rustc'
 47.3 MiB /  47.3 MiB (100 %)   9.9 MiB/s in  4s ETA:  0s

  nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu installed - rustc 1.46.0-nightly (a37c32e2d 2020-06-11)

info: checking for self-updates
```

Now it gives me:

```sh
 cargo +nightly test
error: failed to download `dotenv v0.15.0`

Caused by:
  unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/dotenv-0.15.0/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  readme file with name '../README.md' was not found
```

I have an open issue in their project:
https://github.com/dotenv-rs/dotenv/issues/51

Comment: There is a bug in Cargo.toml for dotenv. This is because the top-level is not actually pushed to up to cargo registry

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this is to change your dependency on `dotenv` to this in your project's Cargo.toml

```
    [dependencies]
    dotenv = { version="0.15.0",git="https://github.com/dotenv-rs/dotenv" }
```